# How to show signs at the end of each line

Tags: line-breaks, list, listchars

is there any plugin that add the signs at the end of the line as shown in the image?

[image: Vim]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for [`:h 'list'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27list%27) and [`:h 'listchars'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27listchars%27) which is a built-in feature in vim/neovim.

For example:

```
set list
set listchars=tab:>-,eol:¶
```

Will show the tab characters as `>-` and add a `¶` at the end of each line.